# Access to font at / from origin / has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: html, css

I am using Coda to upload fonts to my Wordpress page. But I can't get it to work.

[The URL to the page:](https://blomliw.se)

This is the error:

```
Access to font at 'https://www.blomliw.se/blomliw.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts/post_grotesk_book.woff' from origin 'https://blomliw.se' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

After I googled I added this code to my .htacces file without success (got the same error):

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

My css to call for the fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'post_groteskbook';
    src: url('https://www.blomliw.se/blomliw.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts/post_grotesk_book.woff') format('woff'),
            url('https://www.blomliw.se/blomliw.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts/post_grotesk_book.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('https://www.blomliw.se/blomliw.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts/post_grotesk_book.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Anyone have any idea to make this work?

Thanks on behalf!

Comment: Why not change the request URL to `https://blomliw.se/blomliw.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts/post_grotesk_book.otf` (that is, without the www prefix)? If you do that, it won’t be a cross-origin request any longer, and so you won’t run into any CORS problem. But all that aside, it seems like maybe the real problem you’re having is that `https://www.blomliw.se/blomliw.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts/post_grotesk_book.woff` is 404 Not Found. Same for the other font URLs shown in the question.

Comment: Did change the prefix and now the CORS problem is gone, thanks! But as you mentioned, I still have the 404 problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: No, I don’t know what to suggest about the 404 problem. I don’t think anyone here can help you troubleshoot that — I mean, the problem is that the server’s saying the fonts aren’t actually at those URLs. So it seems like you need to figure out what URLs they really are at — what URLs that server sees them at.

Comment: I understand! The strange thing is I have done this before with other webpages and I just copy the url from the uploaded files, so it is so strange that the server itself creates a url that doesn't exist..

Answer (score 0):

Links looking broken

Alternatively download the font and load it locally ;)

```
@font-face { font-family: 'meine-schrift';
             src: local ('meine-schrift')
                  url('pfad/zu/meinerschrift.ttf') format('truetype'); }
```

Comment: I have done that to, but it seems that my links still are broken..

Comment: ok, but to downvote it wasnt necesary i tried to help out

Comment: wasn't me who did that!